# Seperating a Oracle Query with 1.8 million rows into 40,000 row blocks

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a project where I am taking Documents from one system and importing them into another.

The first system has the documents and associated keywords stored. I have a query that will return the results which will then be used as the index file to import them into the new system. There are about 1.8 million documents involved so this means 1.8 million rows (One per document).

I need to divide the returned results into blocks of 40,000 to make importing them in batches of 40,000 at a time, rather than one long import.

I have the query to return the results I need. Just need to know how to take that and break it up for easier import. My apologies if I have included to little information. This is my first time here asking for help.

Comment: 1.8 million divided by 40,000 per batch yields 45 batches.  How is it that running 45 separate imports is preferable to a single import?

Comment: Which version of Oracle?

Comment: How exactly are you going to import them? `impdp`, SQL inserts, old `imp`, etc?

Answer (score 3):

Use the built-in function [`ORA_HASH`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/ORA_HASH.html#GUID-0349AFF5-0268-43CE-8118-4F96D752FDE6) to divide the rows into 45 buckets of roughly the same number of rows. For example:

```
select * from some_table where ora_hash(id, 44) = 0;
select * from some_table where ora_hash(id, 44) = 1;
...
select * from some_table where ora_hash(id, 44) = 44;
```

The function is deterministic and will always return the same result for the same input. The resulting number starts with 0 - which is normal for a hash, but unusual for Oracle, so the query may look off-by-one at first. The hash works better with more distinct values, so pass in the primary key or another unique value if possible. Don't use a low-cardinality column, like a status column, or the buckets will be lopsided.

This process is in some ways inefficient, since you're re-reading the same table 45 times. But since you're dealing with documents, I assume the table scanning won't be the bottleneck here.

Answer (score 1):

A prefered way to *bucketing* the `ID` is to use the [`NTILE`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/NTILE.html#GUID-FAD7A986-AEBD-4A03-B0D2-F7F2148BA5E9) analytic function.

I'll demonstrate this on a simplified example with a table with 18 rows that should be divided in four chunks.

```
select listagg(id,',') within group (order by id)  from tab;
1,2,3,7,8,9,10,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,23,24,25,26
```

Note, that the `ID`s are not consecutive, so no arithmetic can be used - the `NTILE` gets the parameter of the requested number of buckets (4) and calculates the `chunk_id`

```
select id,
ntile(4) over (order by ID) as chunk_id
from  tab
order by id;

        ID   CHUNK_ID
---------- ----------
         1          1
         2          1
         3          1
         7          1
         8          1
         9          2
        10          2
        15          2
        16          2
        17          2
        18          3
        19          3
        20          3
        21          3
        23          4
        24          4
        25          4
        26          4

18 rows selected.
```

All but the last bucket are of the same size, the last one can be smaller.

If you want to calculate the ranges - use simple aggregation

```
with chunk as (
select id,
ntile(4) over (order by ID) as chunk_id
from  tab)
select chunk_id, min(id) ID_from, max(id) id_to
from chunk
group by chunk_id
order by 1;

  CHUNK_ID    ID_FROM      ID_TO
---------- ---------- ----------
         1          1          8
         2          9         17
         3         18         21
         4         23         26
```